# $_GET[""]; inside POST

Tags: php, mysql, post, get

I wanna to just simple get the number from `$sum8 = $_GET["id88"];`
My code looks as follow:

```
    $sum8 = $_GET["id88"];

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            $request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
             $result = new DataSourceResult('mysql:host=server:3306 ;dbname=database_4', 'user_4', 'pass@#');
            $type = $_GET['type'];
            $operation = $_GET['operation'];
            if ($type == "dependency") {
                $columns = array('ID', 'PredecessorID', 
'SuccessorID', 'Type');
                $table = "GanttDependencies";
            } else {
                $columns = array('ID', 'ParentID', 'OrderID', 
'Title', 'Start', 'End', 'PercentComplete', 'Expanded', 'Summary');
                $table = "GanttTasks where project_id =$sum8";
            }
```

And strangely I cannot get the number - it's empty...
If I put below echo like:

```
 echo $test;
```

I see the number from id88 - so it should work...but dosen't
Can you look at this? Or maybe there is some another alternative for this?

URI:

```
<?php
   $val = $_GET['id88'];
   echo "<iframe src='http://www.somepage.com/gantt_chart/gantt_chart?id88=$sum8' width='100%' height='650' scrolling='vertical' frameBorder='0'></iframe>";
?>
```

Comment: what does your request uri look like?

Comment: It depends on where you are posting the form. If the action attribute has `?id88` in it'q query string then you will be able to get that

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood some fundamental things about PHP and variables.

Comment: If I'll remove $_GET["id88"] and put there '8' for example its working so the get works...Anyway  $_GET["id88"]  dosen't

Comment: if your Uri is in an iframe how $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' will work ? are you posting something. please show html for that form.

Comment: The problem is somewhere here: if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

Answer (score 1):

Before your continue reading it will be great if you read [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Look at the last point **Visibility**:

**GET**: Data is visible to everyone in the URL

**POST**: Data is not displayed in the URL

So if you don't have **id88** in the URL it will be empty. If you want to get this value add to the URL.

**Example:** domain.com?id88=88